# How to convert .caf Audio file into .mp4 file in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudiorecorder, avassetexportsession

I'm recording audio using device microphone with `AVAudioRecorder` which return file in **.caf** format that is playable only in Apple devices but not on Android devices. Since Apple is not supporting **.mp3** file so I want to convert it in **.mp4** format before uploading to server.
Is **.mp4** is good for audio only? Can I convert it with `AVAssetExportSession` ?

Following is audio recorder code:

```
func setupAudioRecorder ()
    {

    let fileMgr = FileManager.default
    let dirPaths = fileMgr.urls(for:.documentDirectory,
                                in:.userDomainMask)

    let soundFileURL = dirPaths[0].appendingPathComponent("myaudio.caf")

    let recordSettings =
        [AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.min.rawValue,
         AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16,
         AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
         AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0] as [String : Any]

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(
            AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    do {
        try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: soundFileURL,
                                            settings: recordSettings as [String : AnyObject])
        audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After lot of search i am able to convert **.caf** into **.mp4** using this piece of code

```
    let audioURL = ".caf audio file url"

    let fileMgr = FileManager.default

    let dirPaths = fileMgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                in: .userDomainMask)

    let outputUrl = dirPaths[0].appendingPathComponent("audiosound.mp4")

    let asset = AVAsset.init(url: audioURL)

    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession.init(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)

    // remove file if already exits
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do{
        try? fileManager.removeItem(at: outputUrl)

    }catch{
        print("can't")
    }


    exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4

    exportSession?.outputURL = outputUrl

    exportSession?.metadata = asset.metadata

    exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        if (exportSession?.status == .completed)
        {
            print("AV export succeeded.")

           // outputUrl to post Audio on server

        }
        else if (exportSession?.status == .cancelled)
        {
            print("AV export cancelled.")
        }
        else
        {
            print ("Error is \(String(describing: exportSession?.error))")

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

## `async` mp4 export method

Here is a slightly modified, formatted and shortened variant based on the accepted answer.

It's using an `async` method, you just pass your `.caf` file's `URL` and it returns an `URL` to the exported `.mp4` file:

```swift
/// Exports a `.caf` audio file located at `inputAudioURL` to returned `URL` (in temporary directory).
/// - Parameter inputAudioURL: The `.caf` file's `URL`.
/// - Returns: The output `URL` of the exported `.mp4` file or `nil` if export failed.
func exportToMP4(inputAudioURL: URL) async -> URL? {

    // Extracts file name from input URL and appends `.mp4`
    let fileName = inputAudioURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent.appending(".mp4")

    // Creates output URL for temporary directory.
    guard let outputURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: [NSTemporaryDirectory(), fileName]),
          let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(
            asset: AVAsset(url: inputAudioURL),
            presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
          ) else { return nil }

    // Removes file if it already exists.
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)

    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL

    await exportSession.export()
    if exportSession.status == .completed {
        return outputURL
    } else {
        print("mp4 export did not complete")
        return nil
    }
}
```

## Non `async` variant

In case your codebase does not support `async` methods (or you just don't like them for some reason), here is the same using a completion handler:

```swift
/// Exports a `.caf` audio file located at `inputAudioURL` to returned `URL` (in temporary directory).
/// - Parameter inputAudioURL: The `.caf` file's `URL`.
/// - Returns: The output `URL` of the exported `.mp4` file or `nil` if export failed.
func exportToMP4(inputAudioURL: URL, didFinish: ((URL?) -> Void)?) {

    // Extracts file name from input URL and appends `.mp4`
    let fileName = inputAudioURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent.appending(".mp4")

    // Creates output URL for temporary directory.
    guard let outputURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: [NSTemporaryDirectory(), fileName]),
          let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(
            asset: AVAsset(url: inputAudioURL),
            presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
          ) else { didFinish?(nil); return }

    // Removes file if it already exists.
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)

    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL

    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        if exportSession.status == .completed {
            didFinish?(outputURL)
        } else {
            print("mp4 export did not complete")
            didFinish?(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can record in MPEG4 AAC directly without addition step for converting. Use `AVFormatIDKey` with `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` value and reduce sample rate to 8000 or 16000.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i need .caf too, because before uploading to server i need to play that audio with AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: You can play AAC with AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: My code has: let format = AVAudioFormat( commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44000 etc....).  Are you saying change the commonFormat to .kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC ?  Or is there another step?