# The operation couldn't be completed (OSStatus error 1685348671.)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avfoundation

I'm having trouble playing back an audio file that gets recorded by the user.

**Goal**
For user to to record an audio file, immediately be able to play it back and then choose to either save it, or delete it and try again. If they save it, the path gets saved into Core Data for persistence and ability to play back later.

**Behavior**
Audio file gets saved to Documents directory, but upon attempting playback, Xcode returns the errors

```
2023-06-13 22:25:28.085834-0600 App[2991:2090962]  OpenFromDataSource failed
2023-06-13 22:25:28.085877-0600 App[2991:2090962]  Open failed
Error playing audio: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)
```

I'm able to open the directory on my Mac and manually listen to the .m4a file, so I know it's getting created and is playable. So why is it failing to open the file?

Here is my swift file:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct NewCardAudio: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State private var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?
    @State private var isRecording = false
    @StateObject private var audioPlayerManager = AudioPlayerManager()
    @State private var isPlaying = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                if isRecording {
                    stopRecording()
                } else {
                    startRecording()
                }
            }) {
                Text(isRecording ? "Stop Recording" : "Start Recording")
                    .padding()
                    .background(isRecording ? Color.red : Color.green)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }

            Button(action: {
                if isPlaying {
                    audioPlayerManager.stopPlayback()
                } else {
                    audioPlayerManager.startPlayback()
                }
            }) {
                Text(isPlaying ? "Stop Playback" : "Start Playback")
                    .padding()
                    .background(isPlaying ? Color.red : Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }

            if let audioPlayer = audioPlayerManager.audioPlayer {
                Button(action: {
                    if isPlaying {
                        audioPlayerManager.stopPlayback()
                    } else {
                        audioPlayerManager.startPlayback()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text(isPlaying ? "Stop Playback" : "Start Playback")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var buttonText: String {
        if isRecording {
            return "Stop Recording"
        } else if audioPlayerManager.audioPlayer != nil {
            return isPlaying ? "Stop Playback" : "Start Playback"
        } else {
            return "Start Recording"
        }
    }

    private var buttonColor: Color {
        if isRecording {
            return Color.red
        } else if audioPlayerManager.audioPlayer != nil {
            return Color.blue
        } else {
            return Color.green
        }
    }

    private func startRecording() {
        let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ] as [String : Any]

        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder?.record()
            isRecording = true
        } catch {
            // Handle recording error
            print("Error recording audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    private func stopRecording() {
        audioRecorder?.stop()
        audioRecorder = nil
        isRecording = false

        // Save the recorded audio file into Core Data
        guard let url = audioRecorder?.url else { return }

        let newAudioFile = AudioFile(context: viewContext)
        newAudioFile.fileURL = url.absoluteString

        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Handle Core Data save error
            print("Error saving audio file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    private func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    }
}

class AudioPlayerManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    func startPlayback() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            let audioURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")
            print("Audio File URL: \(audioURL)")
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
            audioPlayer?.delegate = self
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Handle playback error
            print("Error playing audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func stopPlayback() {
        audioPlayer?.stop()
        audioPlayer = nil
    }

    // AVAudioPlayerDelegate methods
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        // Handle playback finish
    }

    private func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70512452/how-to-use-avfaudios-sdk-to-record-play-and-save-audio which helped me get the recordings to play. Thanks